# the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, xamarin.forms

Using c# in an android device from Visual Studio debugging I used:

```
GoogleCredential MyCredential=GoogleCredential.FromJson(json);
```

where json is a string variable:

```
string json1 = "{\n";
string json2 = "\"type\": \"service_account\",\n";
string json3 = "\"project_id\": \"untermeitingen-senior-tennis\",\n";
string json4 = "\"private_key_id\": \"xxxxxxe4ee9d95725507ecbcc3ffa7af7f\",\n";
string json5 = "\"private_key\": \"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\\nxxxxxxxx\\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\\n\",\n";
string json6 = "\"client_email\": \"xxxxxx229633-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com\",\n";
string json7 = "\"client_id\": \"xxxxxxx24866005349\",\n";
string json8 = "\"auth_uri\": \"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth\",\n";
string json9 = "\"token_uri\": \"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token\",\n";
string json10 = "\"auth_provider_x509_cert_url\": \"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs\",\n";
string json11 = "\"client_x509_cert_url\": \"https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/xxxxxx\"\n";
string json12 ="}\n";
string json = json1 + json2 + json3 + json4 + json5 + json6 + json7 + json8 + json9 + json10 + json11 + json12;
```

When I examine the credentials class all items seem to be present except
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS .

An error occurs on this statement:

```
var storage = StorageClient.Create();

string value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS");
```

returns null

I suspect somewhere the credential info is sent to google cloud management which validates
it and sets GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS .

The process functions as expected using windows, but the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
still shows null .

What is going wrong?

Comment: If you're using `GoogleCredential.FromJson(json);`, why do you want to use the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable? If it's returning `null`, have you confirmed that you have set it on your system / set it in your shell before you launch the application / set it in the application's debug config if launching from Visual Studio?

Comment: The error says it isn't set even though I provided the json file data.

Comment: How do I set it in the debug configuration in VS?

Comment: I want it to always be set for users of my APP .

Comment: "even though I provided the json file data" - I don't see you passing the credentials (`GoogleCredential`) to `StorageClient.Create();`? Also _"I want it to always be set for users of my APP"_ - what happens when a user decompiles your app and gets access to your credentials?

Comment: In case it's not clear: writing `GoogleCredential MyCredential=GoogleCredential.FromJson(json);` without using `MyCredential` to create the service objects that you use doesn't do anything by itself. It literally loads the credentials into the `MyCredential` variable and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments, be careful shipping keys; they're easily compromised and, as bearer credentials, may be used by bad actors. In this case (an Android app), it's likely that you would be better placed requiring User credentials (e.g. a Google user account) and requiring your users to follow a 3-step OAuth flow.

You're misunderstanding [Application Default Credentials (ADC)](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/client-libraries#adc) and their relationship to Credentials generally. I encourage you to read the documentation.

To facilitate application simplicity and portability, ADC provides a mechanism to obtain credentials automatically from the environment (sometimes through `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable sometimes through a compute service's access to the Metadata service).

If you were to use ADC (your code doesn't), then you can e.g. `StorageClient.Create()` which is a method that assumes ADC and acquires the credentials automatically.

Since you're specifying a Service Account (I discourage this) and specifying a Key in code, you are going to need to create the credentials and then provide these to [`Create(GoogleCredential,EncryptionKey)`](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1/latest/Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.StorageClient#Google_Cloud_Storage_V1_StorageClient_Create_Google_Apis_Auth_OAuth2_GoogleCredential_Google_Cloud_Storage_V1_EncryptionKey_) you won't need to provide an `EncryptionKey`. I think (haven't tried), you can [`FromJson`](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Apis/latest/Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential#Google_Apis_Auth_OAuth2_GoogleCredential_FromJson_System_String_).

Comment: Well I have read the documentation a number of times and still cannot understand the use of ADC. It seems I need to load Google Client Libraries. Is that the main indicator of using ADC?

Comment: In VS I have loaded Google.Cloud.Storage.V1 which states that it includes the Google CLient Libraries . So how do I reference ADC ?

Comment: See [provide credentials for Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/provide-credentials-adc). In summary when running off Google Cloud, you will need to set the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to point to a Service Account key. When running on Google Cloud (e.g. Cloud Run, Compute Engine etc.), the credentials are obtained from the Metadata service.

Comment: However (!) I think you should probably **not** be using ADC because you should not be running code on an (Android) device as a Service Account but should be using a (human) User account instead.

Comment: That's new to me, a user account and not ADC. I really have a very simple program that uses data from the cloud. It should be easy to allow access to the data, but so far it is very complicated.

Comment: Would Google Drive APIs be better?

Comment: I feel I've answered your original question and provided some recommendations. Good luck!